# Tricking devices that send data to a remote to send data to you on your network

Tags: networking, local-area-network

**Background**: There are numerous device that exist that measure some metric, but then send the data to remote servers for data harvesting (e.g., [owlet](https://owletcare.com), [snoo](https://www.happiestbaby.com/pages/snoo)). My interest in these devices are purely as measuring tools, and I have a strong aversion to providing my data for harvesting to someone else for next to nothing in return (as you can tell from the example too they are data relating to newborns, which makes the privacy issue even more of an ethical concern). Many of these devices do not come with a frontend offline mode for collecting the data yourself even though the instruments work offline (probably because there is a small market for it, and honestly doesn't net the company anything).

**Question**: Are there solutions for setting up a device on a secondary offline network (LAN only), and catching the information that is being transmitted to the remote servers (maybe by tricking the device into thinking it has connected to the remote [which would be impossible as the network is LAN only])? I have found api on github that enable users to harvest the data for themselves, but they all work by collecting the data once it has already been sent to the server (e.g., [owlet](https://github.com/mitch-b/owlet-api-dotnet), [snoo](https://github.com/maebert/snoo)). So they are more interfacing with the (third-party) servers the company have subcontracted rather than the device itself. Perhaps this comes down to a device by device solution as you'd have to crack whatever security they build into the confirming it is their remote server, but I am completely a novice in this field so even mentioning phrases to google and learn more would be helpful.

And the solution need not be what I am thinking, just as long as there would be a way to grab the data from a device that is only connect to an offline network. And I am okay with trial testing the setup with the device connect online (or using that to figure out how to device communicates with remote), the solution just needs to be able to migrate offline.

Thanks.

**Update on train of thought**: This almost seems like a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), but I would think this could be infinitely easier as I am just trying to trick the sender, not both the sender and receiver. So I would imagine I could get around any defenses by issues my own certificates or just agreeing to any mutual authentication (not that I know the first thing about going around doing that, but I have a rudimentary theoretical understanding perhaps). Again I am a 100% uneducated network novice, but this is what is coming to mind. But essentially what I'm wondering now is how to go about this "attack" on a network where I own 100% of everything (devices, data, network). If there are educational resources for implementing this that would be amazing (or any correction to errors in my thought).

Answer (score 1):

In general the enterprise solution is:

*Disallow direct internet access from your own network (segments).*

Only grant internet access to explicitly allowed devices and ideally also only to explicitly defined destinations.

———

If the protocol the devices use allows it and the device supports configuration of an explicit proxy:

(many modern protocols use messages over http(s) and a web proxy is a common proxy server to configure, but proxy server solutions also exist for other protocols) ==>  Set up a proxy server.

Configure the device to use your proxy server

And you can see what messages are sent to whom.

———

If the device does not allow configuration of an explicit proxy - set up a proxy server as a transparent proxy and  redirect traffic at the network layer (for instance http traffic  to api.example.com port 80 ) to your proxy server’s up-address and port

And you can see what messages are sent.

———

When the device communicates over TLS - the transport layer will be encrypted.

You can set up your own root certificate, create for instance a fake certificate for api.example.com and use either your explicit or transparent proxy server to present that certificate and then  attempt to do a man-in-the-middle interception of the TLS traffic.

That should fail, but   might actually work because many devices implement(ed) poor security and will accept all kinds of invalid TLS certificates (signed by untrusted CA’s, expired certificates, certificates for invalid server names etc)

That is more likely to work when you can add your own CA to the list of trusted CA certificates on the device.

When the device uses certificate pinning or uses other forms  stricter security that may still fail.

———

When the protocol is not easy to proxy (and is clear text) you can attempt to record the messages with a packet capture or network sniffer.

———

When rather than,  or in addition to, TLS encryption at the transport layer also the messages themselves are encrypted you may not be able to get at the clear text at all.
 Then you depend on vendor disclosure about what they record and transmit.